# MotionKing 17H2A Stepper Motor with BigEasy Driver not working. Making noise, but not turning!

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I'm trying to make the MotionKing 17H2A stepper motor to work with my BigEasy driver and Arduino Feather 32u4 LoRa.

It's just making some noise, and not turning around.

This is the diagram for the motor. The coils are correctly connected to A and B on the Driver. (Black+Green and Red + Blue).

[image]

Here is the schematics for the motor: https://www.elfadistrelec.no/Web/Downloads/_t/ds/17H2A_eng_tds.pdf

The power supply is 24V at 6.5A.

Here is the code:

```c
/* This is configured for Feather 32u4 LoRa */

int stepPin = 9; // Step pin
int dirPin = 10; // Step direction
int enable = 11;



void setup() {
    pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
    //pinMode(enable, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
    //digitalWrite(enable, LOW);

}

void loop() {
digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH); // Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
// Makes 200 pulses for making one full cycle rotation
for(int x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(500); 
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(500); 
}
delay(1000); // One second delay

digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW); //Changes the rotations direction
// Makes 400 pulses for making two full cycle rotation
for(int x = 0; x < 400; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
}
delay(1000);
        
}
```

Here is the schematics. The power supply is 24V.
[image]

**How can i debug this?**
I have gotten it to work previously, but it's a long time. I suspect it might be the driver, but find it weird that the motor makes all this noise and clicking sounds.

Comment: Please embed circuits for your motor driver circuit.

Comment: Need to see a schematic of your power supply, driver, Arduino and step motor.  Are the grounds connected together?

Comment: Hey @Andyaka. I have now added the schematics.

Comment: @whitegreg56 Yes, the grounds should be connected together.

Comment: No, they are not schematics.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment.

Comment: You are showing nothing connected to BAT on your Arduino. What is the state of the jumpers on the driver board? What is the current limit set to? What you have provided is a wiring diagram...not a schematic. All connections to all pins need to be shown. In the documentation for the driver, there are a number of warnings regarding disconnection of the motor and the possible need for a heat sink.